Bound on norm of difference of powers of self-adjoint operators
I found the following result without any proof. I would be very grateful for any suggestion how to start here.
Let $B_{1}$, $B_{2}$ be two non-negative self-adjoint operators on some Hilbert space with $\left\|B_{j}\right\| \leq a$, $j=1,2$, for some non-negative $a$.
If $0 \leq r \leq 1$, then
$$
\left\|B_{1}^{r}-B_{2}^{r}\right\| \leq C_{r}\left\|B_{1}-B_{2}\right\|^{r},
$$
for some $C_{r}<\infty$.

Do you have a response to the answers below?

In the vocabulary of Aleksandrov and Peller, you are asking for a proof that the function $t \in [0,a]\mapsto t^r$ is operator $r$-Hölder for any $0<r<1$.
There might be an easy proof in this particular case, but Aleksandrov and Peller have proved that any $r$-Hölder function is operator $r$-Hölder whenever $r<1$ (this is well-known to be false for Lipschitz functions, i.e. for $r=1$). See the above link.

Your inequality holds, with the best possible constant factor $C_r=1$ for all $r\in(0,1]$. This follows immediately from Theorem 1 of Birman–Koplienko–Solomyak (BKS). The proof is rather short, modulo an interpolation theorem by Mityagin.
This result by BKS is referred to in the paper by Aleksandrov and Peller linked in the answer by Mikael de la Salle.
